# Subdomain on Azure VM IIS (x.y.cloudapp.net)

Tags: iis, umbraco, subdomain, azure-virtual-machine

Im pretty new with azure, but iv'e set up a VM running windows 2008 server, with IIS hosting  a Umbraco Solution...

I can browse the site perfectly using "x.cloudapp.net".
But i have setup some hostnames in Umbraco for subsites.

Fx. i got "y.x.cloudapp.net". and its also added to IIS bindings.
But this is not browsable at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, you can't add additional subdomains cloudapp.net beyond the assigned Azure subdomain, you can subdomain your own custom domain.

Comment: Is this still the case @BartCzemiciki?

Comment: Yes, it is, unfortunately. As a bad workaround you can edit host files on your local machine, but that's a very local workaround.